# I need assistance converting Scaled data from StandardScaler in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that need to be scaled in Python.  However, when I scale the data with StandardScaler(), the data get reshaped to an array and i also lose the data header.
How do I convert the data back to a pd.DataFrame so I can have the headers back in place as they were before the scaling?

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
train_t = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(scaler.fit_transform(train)).reshape(1458,218), index=list(train.columns))
print(train_t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
train_t = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(train), columns = train.columns)
```